# Data augmentation using Keras image generator makes training very slow

Tags: computer-vision, keras, keras-2

I have a big data set. Data is about 100k. I further augmented data using **ImageDataGenerator** . But it makes training process very slow. Without keras image generator function, training process took about 3 mins but when I use ImageDataGenerator function it took about more that 3 hours. I used this code for image augmentation. How to improve the performance?

```python
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                             vertical_flip=True,
                             featurewise_center=True,
                             featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             rotation_range=90.)
datagen.fit(data)
epochs = 50

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(data, label, batch_size=128),
                    steps_per_epoch=patches.shape[0],
                    epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: I've noticed exactly the same, using an RTX2060, each epoch took 0.1s with image dataset preloaded to a np array. Then moving to an ImageDataGenerator with augmentation each epoch is taking 10s. I believe this is a Keras issue and a more efficient way is to use tf.data to build a pipeline that can benefit from parallel compute, although I've not yet tried it (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things to try.

**Preprocess Input**

I'm not familiar with using this parameter `featurewise_std_normalization=True`, but I would try using a preprocessing function instead. If it's calculating this transformation on every batch then it's likely consuming a lot of resources. You could transform all of your data prior to training to avoid the constant calculations.

**Reduce Dimensionality**

You could shrink the dimensions of your image if they are greater than 224x224. You could even try to go smaller in many cases.

**Reduce Steps per Epoch**

Take a look at the steps per epoch. I'm not sure what is being input now based on the code above (patches.shape[0]) but I wouldn't go much higher than data_size // batch_size if the training was that slow (you can go higher since it's augmenting the data but it takes more time).

**Upgrade Equipment**
If none of that works I'd recommend getting a GPU if you don't already have one. If this is being done on a CPU then that explains it. Image transformations are relatively large matrix calculations for a CPU.

Comment: I can confirm that it does not calculate featurewise_std_normalization on each batch.